# Show confidence interval in legend of plot in Python / Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am generating some scatter plots with linear regression and confidence interval using `seaborn` on Python, with the `sns.regplot` function. I could find a way to show the Regression line in the legend, but I would also like to add the Confidence Interval in the legend (with the transparent blue as the reference colour).

Here is the code I have and the result I get so far.

```
Tobin_Nationality_Reg = sns.regplot(x="Nationality_Index_Normalized",
                        y="Tobins_Q_2017",
                        data=Scatter_Plot,
                        line_kws={'label':'Regression line'})

plt.xlabel("Nationality Index")
plt.ylabel("Tobin's Q")
plt.legend()`
plt.savefig('Tobin_Nationality_Reg.png')
```

Here is the output I currently get:
Scatter Plot

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how I could do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is no clean way to do this, because `seaborn` does not expose keyword arguments for the `fill_between` call that plots the confidence interval.

However, it can be done by modifying the `label` attribute of the `PolyCollection` directly:

```
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 20)

ax = sns.regplot(x, y, line_kws={'label': 'Regression line'})
ax.collections[1].set_label('Confidence interval')
ax.legend()
```

[image]